# Como pegar o nome da variável usada no argumento da função?

Tags: php

- **Script1.php**

Aqui script1.php chama a função que está no script2:

```
sendData($variavel);
```

- **Script2.php**

A função recebe o valor e inclui o script 3 para receber os valores do argumentos:

```
sendData(){
    $getFirstArgumentValue = func_get_arg(0);
    // $getVariableName = ...
    sendVariableNameAndValue($getFirstArgument);
    // global $variavel;
    include('script3.php');
}
```

- **Script3.php**

Em script3.php é declarado a variável chamada no script1.php, e é notório que uma mensagem de error aparecerar:

```
echo($variavel);
```

Aparece a mensagem de erro no script3 avisando que $variavel não foi declarada.

**A pergunta é:**

Como faço para declarar em script3, a mesma variável que foi declarada em script1, passando pela função declarada no script2 e receber esse valor em script3?

Nesse caso a função sendData teria que pegar o valor do argumento e também o nome da variável usada para enviar esse valor?

Seria possível enviar o valor e o nome da variável?

Comment: Só por curiosidade, onde você usaria isso?

Comment: Detalhei melhor minha resposta, veja se alguma das opções se enquadra na sua questão...

Comment: Há soluções melhores para passar argumentos... se puder poste qual a aplicação você está fazendo

Comment: Como solução alternativa, estou usando uma array. `$data['variavel']`, porem ainda é preciso declarar $data no script3.php. E queria declarar em script3.php, qualquer variavel que eu quiser, mas que tenha o mesmo nome da variavel em script1.php

Comment: Descreva a função da sua pagina `script3.php`, o que ela faz exatamente... O exemplo que você deu é muito superficial

Comment: Então use $GLOBALS['variavel'] ela é super global e não precisa ser declarada e terá o mesmo valor de $variavel do script1.php

Comment: user14319, um dica coloque todo código!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a atualização do PHP 5.6, foi lançada as "[Variadic functions via ...](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)"

Consegui criar um código limpo e claro:

- **Script1.php**

  ```
  $variavel = 'foo';
  sendData($variavel);
  ```
- **Script2.php**

  ```
  public function sendData(...$variables){
      foreach($variables as $variableValue){
          foreach($GLOBALS as $globalName => $globalValue){
              if($globalValue === $variableValue){
                  global $$globalName;
              }
           }
      }

      include('script3.php');
  }
  ```
- **Script3.php**

  ```
  echo($variavel);
  ```

Para que esse código funcione, a função deve ser chamada com a variável em um escopo global. Por exemplo: se a função for chamada dentro de outra função esse código não funciona, a não ser que você declare a variavel enviada como global. eCode:

```
sampleMethod(){
    $variavel = 'bar';
    global $variavel;
    sendData($variavel);
}
```

Existe outro método para pegar o nome da variável com [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), mas acho que a questão já foi respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que não seja possível, a única alternativa que me ocorre, seria passar o nome da variável como string no parâmetro:

```
$variavel = 'Olá mundo!';

sendData('variavel');

function sendData(){
    $getFirstArgumentValue = func_get_arg(0);
    global $$getFirstArgumentValue;
    include('script3.php');
}
```

**script3.php**

```
<?php

echo($variavel);

?>
```

Mas de qualquer forma você estará limitado a variável ter sempre este nome: `$variavel` e acho que o seu problema é que você precisa aplicar a função `sendData()` a outras variáveis, então deve usar algo assim:

```
$outra_variavel = 'Olá mundo!';

sendData($outra_variavel);

function sendData($data){
    include('script3.php');
}
```

**script3.php**

```
<?php

echo($data);

?>
```

Note que nesse exemplo não é preciso definir a variável `$data` como global, pois ao fazer o `include('script3.php');` dentro da função `sendData` ela estará no mesmo escopo, ou seja é o mesmo que:

```
$outra_variavel = 'Olá mundo!';

sendData($outra_variavel);

function sendData($data){
    echo($data);
}
```

Que a proposito seria uma ótima solução, eu particularmente nunca utilizei includes dentro de funções, pois além de ficar desorganizado, a cada chamada da função o PHP vai recarregar o arquivo do disco...

Comment: Na verdade isso não resolve. A solução seria enviar o nome da variável de forma 'recursiva'.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas a pergunta já foi finalizada (respondida)!

Answer (score 0):

em script3 declare a variável com mesmo nome **global**, sendo classe ou não que fará o acesso no script3 vai funcionar!

Comment: Não resolve o problema.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas a pergunta já foi finalizada (respondida)!

Answer (score 0):

O que provavelmente queres fazer é ter um template `script3.php` e carregar a informação necessária através da função `sendData`, se for esse o caso poderás fazer do seguinte modo.

```
function sendData(array $data = array()) {
    extract($data);
    include 'script3.php';
}
```

Terás de definir uma `array` do estilo:

```
$myData = array(
    'var1' => 'valor',
    'var2' => 'xpto',
);
```

Para que possas chamar a função `sendData($myData);`

Assim poderás utilizar as variáveis que bem precisares no **script3.php**, ex:

```
echo $var1;

if (isset($var2)) {
    echo 'var2 também existe com o seguinte valor: ' . $var2;
}
```

**PS:** Se quiseres que a função `sendData` devolva o resultado gerado pelo `script3` como um string, poderás fazer o seguinte:

```
/**
 * Sends some data
 * @param  array  $data Variáveis a utilizar
 * @return string       Resultado
 */
function sendData(array $data = array()) {
    ob_start();
    extract($data);
    include 'script3.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas a pergunta já foi finalizada (respondida)!

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

script1.php

```
$data['variavel'] = 1;
getData($data);
```

ou então

```
getData(array('variavel'=>1));
```

script2.php

```
function getData($arr){
     extract($arr);
     include 'script3.php';
}
```

script3.php

```
echo $variavel;
```

Qualquer indice que você definir no array que vai como parametro para a função `getData()` será criado pelo comando `extract()` no arquivo script3.php

Documentação:
http://php.net/extract

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas a pergunta já foi finalizada (respondida)!