# Nome da variável passada no argumento da função

Tags: php, funções, variáveis, argumento

#### Situação

Estou querendo desenvolver esta função

```
function ve($var, $dieAfter = false){

    $nomeDaVar = ????; 

    echo '<pre>';
    echo '$'.$nomeDaVar." = ";
    var_export($var);
    echo '</pre>';

    if ($dieAfter){
        exit();
    }
}
```

Em `$nomeDaVar` quero pegar o nome da variável passada no argumento `$var`.

#### Exemplo

```
function pessoa(){

    $dadosPessoa = array(
        'nome' => 'Guilherme',
        'sobrenome' => 'Lautert'
    );
    ve($dadosPessoa, 1);
}
```

#### Resultado desejado

```
$dadosPessoa = array(
    'nome' => 'Guilherme',
    'sobrenome' => 'Lautert'
)
```

#### Testes

```
debug_backtrace()   // Não me retorna o nome da variável;
func_get_arg(0)     // Não me retorna o nome da variável, apenas o array;
get_defined_vars()  // Me retorna o nome 'var' nao 'dadosPessoa';
$GLOBALS            // Não possui a variável;
```

#### Links

- Esta pergunta tem título similar mas não se aplica : [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29254/como-pegar-o-nome-da-vari%C3%A1vel-usada-no-argumento-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- Esta pergunta tem o mesmo intuito mas não teve o mesmo resultado : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php)

  - A segunda resposta resolve, mas não me parece prático.

Comment: Mais uma vez não percebo o -1 da pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não consegue fazer isto e nem existe qualquer motivo para fazê-lo.

Na verdade até poderia ter alguma forma. Desconheço uma especificamente mas como PHP é uma linguagem basicamente interpretada, é possível que exista uma API que permita ter acessoa esta informação, ou em último caso você poderia tentar carregar o próprio fonte do seu *script*, analisá-lo e achar a informar. Mas não é algo simples e seria ridículo fazer isto.

Se é apenas curiosidade, ela está satisfeita. Se realmente quer usar isto em algo real, repense seu *design*, algo muito errado está sendo feito.

O que você quer fazer é fácil de resolver, basta criar um parâmetro com o nome da variável passada. Eu sei que você quer evitar isto mas existe um motivo para as variáveis terem escopo e o que você está tentando fazer é justamente passar por cima disto. Funções foram feitas para serem independentes, não precisarem saber nada do que foi usado para chamá-la.

E isto tem um outro problema, você está querendo uma informação que pode nem existir.Eu já falei em alguns lugares que as pessoas se confundem com variáveis e expressões. Uma argumento de uma chamada de função pede uma expressão e não uma variável. Se esta expressão é apenas uma variável, isto é apenas uma coincidência. Qual é o nome da variável se você chamar isto:

```
function pessoa() {
    ve(array(
        'nome' => 'Guilherme',
        'sobrenome' => 'Lautert'
    ), 1);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/AsArgument.php).

Ou seja, você quer uma informação que nem sequer é o argumento da função. Tem que ir mais longe para obter. E quão longe deve ir?

O máximo que você pode obter de forma mais simples é o nome do parâmetro, mas este você já sabe como conseguir. E na verdade nem precisa, você já sabe qual é ele quando está codificando. Ele não é variável em tempo de execução.

[Diferença entre argumento e parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Outra solução é fazer a variável ser global, mas por favor, não faça isto em hipótese alguma.

Comment: De fato @bigown, esqueci-me da questão de escopo, e pensei unicamente em praticidade, a razão do desenvolvimento desta função é testes, então não terá problema passar o segundo parâmetro com nome da variável. Obrigado o senso critico, explicativo.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor que você vai conseguir fazer é dar dinamicamente um nome à variável.

```
$var1 = "nome";
$var2 = "idade";

$$var1 = "Rafael";
$$var2 = "25";
```

Assim você pode acessar  `$nome` e `$idade` que elas existem. Faça o teste:

```
if ($nome == "Rafael")
{
    echo $var1." = ".$nome;
}

if ($idade == "Rafael")
{
    echo $var2." = ".$idade;
}
```

Dessa forma você terá acesso aos nome das variáveis. Não vejo outro jeito além desse, desculpe...